# Prolog Recursion removing elements at index that is multiples of n from a list where n is any number

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

This is my first time asking a question here but I have a problem that I really can't wrap my head around which is Prolog recursion especially when it deals with list. So the task that I am supposed to solve is to write a drop predicate that works like this. For example, `drop([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 2, L)` where `L = [1,3,5,7,9]` and `N=n` where elements at position n, 2n, 3n.... will be removed. The list starts from 1 is another thing to be noted.

Here is my attempt so far and thought process:

```
drop([], _, []).

indexOf([X|_], X, 1). %Using 1 because the question says the first element starts from 1.

indexOf([_|Ys], Y , I):-
    indexOf(Ys, Y, N),
    I is N + 1.

drop([X|Xs], Y, [X|_]) :-
    indexOf([X|Xs] , X , A),
    Z is A mod Y,
    Z \== 0.

drop([X|Xs], Y, Zs) :-
    %indexOf([X|Xs], X, A),
    drop(Xs, Y, Zs).
```

I created an `indexOf` predicate to find the index of the elements starting from 1 . Next, my idea was to use the my first drop recursive case (in the code above it is the 5th case) to check and see whether the position of the element returns a remainder of zero when divided by the `Y` (second input). if it does not return a remainder of zero, then the `X` remains inside the list and is not dropped. Then, prolog moves on to the 2nd drop recursive case which can only be arrived when `Z=0` and it will drop `X` from the list to return `Z`s. In essence, an element with index n, 2n, 3n... that is returned by `indexOf` will be dropped if it does not return a remainder of zero when divided by `Y` (second input).

I have not learnt Cut at this point of the course at the moment. I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction. I have been working on this for almost a day.

I am still trying to adapt the logic and declarative thinking in this programming paradigm. I would appreciate it if you could share with me, how did you personally go about mastering Logic programming?

Comment: Your second drop predicate has `_` in the tail of the result, which isn't good. That means your results will have that anonymous variable. So you obviously don't mean that. Think of these as rules and try to read them as such. `drop([X|Xs], Y, [X|_]) :-...` is *The list `[X|Xs]` with the `Y`-th element dropped is `[X|_]` if...*. What makes that true? Certainly you would need `Y > 1`, but `[X|_]` needs a real tail, and the value of the tail will be determined by your rule.

Comment: Isn't the first result `A` of `indexOf([X|Xs], X, A)` always going to be `A = 1`? One falacy of the `indexOf` strategy is that you don't really know what the `Y`-th element is going to be until you get there, so you don't have it to take the index of it. You really just want a simple counter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just saw this as I tried re-attempting it again this morning. I was looking at gtrace and could't understand why my results turn out like [a | _G264]. I finally understand it now thanks to your first comment. I shouldn't use anonymous variable at my results as I need it to instantiate/store my result.

Comment: YES! I noticed the fallacy in using the indexOf strategy this morning and I tried using an accumulator to act as a simple counter but couldn't get it to work as well. Not really sure how to create a counter in Prolog since in Java all I had to do was create a local variable i. I'm going to read your long response below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, looking at your approach, there's a flaw with using the `indexOf/3`. That is, at a given point in time when you need to know the index of what you're removing, you don't know what the item is yet until you get to it. At that point, the index is `1`.

That's one issue with the following rule:

```
drop([X|Xs], Y, [X|_]) :-
    indexOf([X|Xs], X, A),
    Z is A mod Y,
    Z \== 0.
```

The first subquery: `indexOf([X|Xs], X, A)` will succeed with `A = 1` on its first attempt, just by definition (of course, `X` has index `1` in list `[X|Xs]`. As it succeeds, then the next line `Z is A mod Y` yields `1` since `1 mod Y` is always `1` if `Y > 0`. And therefore, `Z \== 0` will always succeed in this case.

Thus, you get the result: `[X|_]` where `X` is the first element of the list. So the first solution you get for, say, `drop([1,2,3,4], 2, L).` is `L = [1|_]`. Your third `drop/3` predicate clause just recurses to the next element in the list, so then it will succeed the second clause the same way, yielding, `L = [2|_]`, and so on...

Starting from the top, here's a way to think about a problem like this.

**Auxiliary predicate**

I know I want to remove every `N`-th element, so it helps to have a counter so that every time it gets to `N` I will ignore that element. This is done with an auxiliary predicate, `drop/4` which will also have a recurring counter in addition to the original `N`:

```
drop(L, N, R) :-
    drop(L, N, 1, R).   % Start counter at 1
```

**Base rule**

*If I drop any element from the empty list, I get the empty list*. It doesn't matter what elements I drop. That's expressed as:

```
drop([], _, _, []).
```

You have this rule expressed correctly already. The above is the 4-argument version.

**Recursive rule 1 - The `N`-th element**

*I have list `[X|Xs]` and `X` is the `N`-th element index, then the result is `R` if I skip `X`, reset my index counter to `1`, and drop the `N`-th element from `Xs`*:

```
drop([_|Xs], N, N, R) :-   % I don't care what the element is; I drop it
    drop(Xs, N, 1, R).
```

**Recursive rule 2 - Other than the `N`-th element**

*I have list `[X|Xs]` and `X` is the `A`-th element (< `N`), then the result is `[X|R]` if I increment my index counter (`A`), and drop `N`-th elements from `Xs` with my updated index counter*:

```
drop([X|Xs], N, A, [X|R]) :-
    A < N,
    NextA is A + 1,
    drop(Xs, N, NextA, R).
```

Those are all the needed rules (4 of them).

Comment: This what just what I needed. :) Thanks for introducing me to the concept of auxiliary predicate and for the clear step-by-step explanation to how you would think about the problem. I never knew you could do it like this. I have a quick question regarding order of recursive rules. In this particular question, I noticed that if I swap around the recursive rules, it still solves the problem which is due to Prolog searching from top-bottom every time drop is called. I would like to ask whether is there any scneario/example where certain recursive rules have to be placed first before another?

Comment: @t22000 order of the rules can make a difference sometimes. It depends upon the rules. In this case, the two recursive rules are mutually exclusive, one covering the case where the counter is `N` and the other where the counter is `< N`. But, In general, you want to put the specific (*e.g.*, base case) rules first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I have gotten a lot better at Prolog with your help although not very good yet and managed to finish my other assignments. :D I would like to give you a vote up but my reputation is not up yet :(

Comment: @t22000 no worries. I'm glad it helped you learn to "think in Prolog". :)